# /dev/video* shows 16 devices

Tags: webcam, motion

I want to capture a video stream using motion, but the FPS is REALLY low and I have the feeling that something is wrong

`ls /dev/video*`

shows 16 devices, is that normal? The Webcam is a USB Webcam by Aukey